# Sending Selected button name through Vue / Axios

Tags: php, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a button within a file that looks like the below

**UPDATED**

```
<div v-for="button in buttons"
    :key="button.value"
    class="gc gc-one-third gc-whole-to2">
    <button @click.stop.prevent="onClick(button)">{{ button.from }} <br /> {{ button.to }}</button>
</div>
```

How do I push the BUTTON TEXT part of the clicked button (There are 3 in total) through the form using Axios and Vue as it says that I cannot use v-model.

**UPDATED**

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            step: 1,
            counter: 0,
            buttons: [{
                value: 1,
                from: '£3,000',
                to: 'TO £5,000'
            }, {
                value: 2,
                from: '£5,000',
                to: 'TO £10,000'
            }, {
                value: 3,
                from: 'OVER',
                to: '£10,0000'
            }],
            debt: {
                name: null,
                email: null,
                tel: null
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        prev() {
            this.step--;
        },
        next() {
            this.step++;
        },
        onClick(button) {
            this.counter = button.value;
        },
        submit() {
            axios.post('post.php', {
                'name': this.debt.name,
                'email': this.debt.email,
                'tel': this.debt.tel,
            }).then(response => {
                console.log('success', response.data.message)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error.response)
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks, Jake.

Comment: What's `@hasClicked()`?

Comment: @EmileBergeron That was just for testing, I've removed that from the above code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the value of the `counter`

```
    submit() {
        axios.post('post.php', {
            'name': this.debt.name,
            'email': this.debt.email,
            counter: this.counter
        }).then(response => {
            console.log('success', response.data.message)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response)
        });
    }
```

If you need the caption of the button

```
<button ref="myBtn" @click.stop.prevent="counter = 1">VALUE</button>

    submit() {
        axios.post('post.php', {
            'name': this.debt.name,
            'email': this.debt.email,
             value: this.$refs.myBtn.innerHTML
        }).then(response => {
            console.log('success', response.data.message)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response)
        });
    }
```

### UPDATE

If you have a form with 10 buttons and want to post the caption of the button which was clicked with AXIOS:

```
<form>
  <div>
    some text <button type="button" @click="submit">VALUE</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    some other text <button type="button" @click="submit">OTHER VALUE</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    something else <button type="button" @click="submit">EVEN OTHER</button>
  </div>
</form>


<script>
submit(event) {
    axios.post('post.php', {
        'name': this.debt.name,
        'email': this.debt.email,
         value: event.target ? event.target.innerHTML : ""
    }).then(response => {
        console.log('success', response.data.message)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response)
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm getting a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined. Also how would this work for multiple buttons in which the selected button text value gets posted? Thanks

Comment: Did you add the `ref` attribute to your button as shown in the example ? See my updated answer.

Comment: Hey I've updated my code but I'm still having issues getting the button text to come through via Axios

Comment: okay, you have 3 buttons which by default are of type SUBMIT. You prevent the default action (which is to submit the form) and also stop the click event propagation to parent elements. So `counter` contains the value of the last clicked button. You need one more variable, e.g. `lastButton` to store the `button` object. Then in `submit()` method you will get what you need from the `lastButton` object - supposedly the `from` and `to` keys.